# Exception: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'params' is not present

Tags: java, jquery, spring, datatables

When i clicked the edit button the values from dataTable should display in form. But somehow it doesn't work. Below are my codes for reference.

Call DataTable:

```
$("#tranTable").on("click", "#edit", function(){
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");

    $("#Own-Account").removeClass("hidden");
    $("fieldset#addToListMethod").addClass("hidden");
    $("fieldset#Own-Account #templateTrxId").val( row.find("[name$=templateTrxId]").val() )
    $("fieldset#Own-Account #templateId")   .val( row.find("[name$=templateId]").val() )
    $("fieldset#newFT #fromAccNo")          .val( row.find("[name$=fromAccNo]").val() ), 
    $("fieldset#newFT #methodOfTransfer")   .val( row.find("[name$=methodOfTransfer]").val() ), 
    $("fieldset#Own-Account #toAccNo")      .val( row.find("[name$=toAccNo]").val() ), 
    $("fieldset#Own-Account #paymentRef")   .val( row.find("[name$=paymentRef]").val() ),
    $("fieldset#Own-Account #amount")       .val( row.find("[name$=amount]").val() ),

    //hidden
    $("fieldset#Own-Account #otherPaymentDetail").val( row.find("[name$=otherPaymentDetail]").val() ),
    $("fieldset#Own-Account #email1").val( row.find("[name$=email1]").val() ),          
    $("fieldset#Own-Account #email2").val( row.find("[name$=email2]").val() ),
    $("fieldset#Own-Account #sms1").val( row.find("[name$=sms1]").val() ),
    $("fieldset#Own-Account #sms2").val( row.find("[name$=sms2]").val() ),
    $("fieldset#Own-Account #purpose").val( row.find("[name$=purpose]").val() )
    $("fieldset#Own-Account #isEdit").val(1);
    $("fieldset#Own-Account #dataTableRowId").val(row.data("row-id"));


});
```

Comment: It seems what you post is not the real part of your question. The exception is obvious from your service and it could be triggered by your click but obviously you do not post the request part. You should check the real request to your web server not behavior after the request done. If you are not sure, you can publish  you project on github and post the repository here to let us know, it could be helpful.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the exception, your problem likely occurs because the `@RequestMapping` doesn't find the parameter being sent from previous the page.

In this case, it is likely like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/check")
public String getID(@RequestParam(value = "params") String params){
//your logic code here
}
```

From here, the exception occurs when the `@RequestMapping` doesn't find `"params"`:

```
@RequestParam(value = "params") String params
```

This happens because, by default, `@RequestParam` tries to get the value. It then returns an exception when the value is not found.

So you have two ways to resolve this,

1. You can supply the URL `/check` with a `params` variable or,
2. You can change the `@RequestParam` requirement to false like this:

   @RequestParam(value = "params", required = false) String params

Take note that this is an example to reflect your scenario and problem. Gud luk.

Answer (score 1):

It was fixed by adding `required = false` like this:

Before adding:

```
public String saveOrUpdate(
    @RequestParam("studentId") String studentId,
    @RequestParam("name") String name) {
```

After adding:

```
public String saveOrUpdate(
        @RequestParam(value = "studentId", required = false) String studentId,
        @RequestParam("name") String name) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message. My mistake was that I wrote on Javascript side:

```
MyService.getStatus(vm.id);
```

instead of:

```
MyService.getStatus({id : vm.id});
```

so the parameter was not named as expected on Java side:

```
@GetMapping("/myservice/getStatus")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<String> getStatus(@RequestParam("id") Long id) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `@RequestParam(value = "params") String params` with `@PathVariable String id`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).