# Required String parameter 'email' is not present

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, postman

I can't make a request via postman, I checked everything, my email is represented as varchar(255) in my database. I use postgresql. Error: Required String parameter 'email' is not present. I used [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37107570/exception-org-springframework-web-bind-missingservletrequestparameterexception) and set it like this: `@RequestParam(value = "params", required = false) String params` for each received value, but this didn't help, as the program reported that we didn't send anything. What does this have to do with? The request is correct, as well as the accepted parameters are correct.

What the request looks like:

```
{
    "email" : "qwerty@mail.ru",
    "name" : "Vasya",
    "surname" : "Puk",
    "phone" : 1234562,
    "role":"ADMIN"
}
```

Entity USER

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "task")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.REFRESH
    })
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private List<Role> role;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Contract> contract;

    @Column(name = "surname", nullable = false)
    private String surname;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "phone", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer phone;
}
```

The controller that accepts:

```
@PostMapping
    public String userPostAdd(@RequestParam String email, @RequestParam Integer phone, @RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String surname, @RequestParam String role) {
        Roles roles = null;
        System.out.println("TEST");
        System.out.println(roles.equalsName(role));
        System.out.println("TEST");
        //if ()
        //userRepository.save(requestUserDetails);
        return "User add;
    }
```

Repo:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

Adding logs

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\jbr\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=55224:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\VGilenko\IdeaProjects\taskspring\target\classes;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.12.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.12.1.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.12.1\log4j-api-2.12.1.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.28\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.28.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.25\snakeyaml-1.25.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.4\aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\3.4.1\HikariCP-3.4.1.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.1\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.28\slf4j-api-1.7.28.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-aspects-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-rest\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-data-rest-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-json-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.10.0\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.10.0\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.10.0\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-validation\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-validation-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\jakarta\validation\jakarta.validation-api\2.0.1\jakarta.validation-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.17.Final\hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-rest-webmvc\3.2.0.RELEASE\spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-rest-core\3.2.0.RELEASE\spring-data-rest-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\hateoas\spring-hateoas\1.0.0.RELEASE\spring-hateoas-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\com\jayway\jsonpath\json-path\2.4.0\json-path-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\net\minidev\json-smart\2.3\json-smart-2.3.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\net\minidev\accessors-smart\1.2\accessors-smart-1.2.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\5.0.4\asm-5.0.4.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\plugin\spring-plugin-core\2.0.0.RELEASE\spring-plugin-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\atteo\evo-inflector\1.2.2\evo-inflector-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.10.0\jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.10.0\jackson-core-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.10.0\jackson-annotations-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.27\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.27\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.27.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.27\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.27.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\postgresql\postgresql\42.2.16\postgresql-42.2.16.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-qual\3.5.0\checker-qual-3.5.0.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.4.20.Final\hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.1.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\javax\persistence\javax.persistence-api\2.2\javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.24.0-GA\javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.10.1\byte-buddy-1.10.1.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec\1.1.1.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.1.3.Final\jandex-2.1.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.0\classmate-1.5.0.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\javax\activation\javax.activation-api\1.2.0\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\dom4j\dom4j\2.1.3\dom4j-2.1.3.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.0.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.3.1\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.2\jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.2\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.2\txw2-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.8\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\jvnet\staxex\stax-ex\1.8.1\stax-ex-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\fastinfoset\FastInfoset\1.2.16\FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar innotechnum.task.Application

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.0.RELEASE)

2020-09-25 19:26:12.934  INFO 7764 --- [           main] innotechnum.task.Application             : Starting Application on VGilenko with PID 7764 (C:\Users\VGilenko\IdeaProjects\taskspring\target\classes started by VGilenko in C:\Users\VGilenko\IdeaProjects\taskspring)
2020-09-25 19:26:12.939  INFO 7764 --- [           main] innotechnum.task.Application             : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-09-25 19:26:14.198  INFO 7764 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-09-25 19:26:14.265  INFO 7764 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 59ms. Found 4 repository interfaces.
2020-09-25 19:26:14.930  INFO 7764 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-09-25 19:26:15.691  INFO 7764 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-09-25 19:26:15.707  INFO 7764 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-09-25 19:26:15.707  INFO 7764 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.27]
2020-09-25 19:26:15.845  INFO 7764 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-09-25 19:26:15.845  INFO 7764 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2770 ms
2020-09-25 19:26:16.224  INFO 7764 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-09-25 19:26:16.296  INFO 7764 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.20.Final
2020-09-25 19:26:16.512  INFO 7764 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-09-25 19:26:16.745  INFO 7764 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-09-25 19:26:16.882  INFO 7764 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-09-25 19:26:16.907  INFO 7764 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
Hibernate: alter table if exists task.city add constraint FKtjrg7h2j3ehgycr3usqjgnc2u foreign key (id) references task.house
2020-09-25 19:26:17.915  WARN 7764 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table if exists task.city add constraint FKtjrg7h2j3ehgycr3usqjgnc2u foreign key (id) references task.house" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table if exists task.city add constraint FKtjrg7h2j3ehgycr3usqjgnc2u foreign key (id) references task.house" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:433) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:249) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:316) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:469) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at innotechnum.task.Application.main(Application.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: INSERT или UPDATE в таблице "city" нарушает ограничение внешнего ключа "fktjrg7h2j3ehgycr3usqjgnc2u"
  Подробности: Ключ (id)=(1) отсутствует в таблице "house".
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:473) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:393) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:322) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:284) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:279) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    ... 33 common frames omitted

2020-09-25 19:26:17.957  INFO 7764 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-09-25 19:26:17.963  INFO 7764 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-09-25 19:26:19.150  INFO 7764 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-09-25 19:26:19.635  INFO 7764 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-09-25 19:26:19.639  INFO 7764 --- [           main] innotechnum.task.Application             : Started Application in 7.149 seconds (JVM running for 7.817)
2020-09-25 19:26:35.874  INFO 7764 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-09-25 19:26:35.875  INFO 7764 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-09-25 19:26:35.904  INFO 7764 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 29 ms
2020-09-25 19:26:35.958  WARN 7764 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'email' is not present]
```

Comment: are you having a rest project ?

Comment: @AnishB. yes. I write only the back, without the front. Because I'm just learning

Comment: Then don't go for requestparam approach.

Comment: @AnishB. Why? How best to use it. I wanted to make an API in the future, respectively, so it seemed like a good option.

Comment: As you are using post method and you are send a secure data. So, better consume data as JSON single object.

Comment: What does this mean? I already use JSON

Comment: Send data as RequestBody JSON

Comment: @AnishB. {
    "email" : "qwerty@mail.ru",
    "name" : "Vasya",
    "surname" : "Puk",
    "phone" : 1234562,
    "role":"ADMIN"
}  it's JSON? I used him in postman

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This controller seems to be incorrect.

```
@PostMapping
public String userPostAdd(@RequestParam String email, @RequestParam Integer phone, @RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String surname, @RequestParam String role) {
     //body
}
```

It should be like this :

```
@PostMapping
public String userPostAdd(@RequestBody User user) {
     //body
}
```

User is your object request, similar as your User entity

`Error executing DDL "alter table if exists task.city add` check your entities then update your database schema accrodingly