# Why am I getting a "Required request parameter <> for method parameter type Long is not present" when it is being correctly set in my API call?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-boot, rest

I have encountered a problem quite similar to the one described in [this thread](https://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37107570/exception-org-springframework-web-bind-missingservletrequestparameterexception)

However none of the solutions proposed there have helped so I would appreciate any assistance anyone here can offer.

I have a webpage that should get data from a Spring Boot Rest endpoint using an Ajax.Data call (described [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data)).

My Spring Boot Rest API is as follows

```
@PostMapping(value = "/ajax/my-ajax-api")
public MyResponseDto runThisMethod(@RequestParam Long myId, @RequestParam Integer myOtherParameter) {
///
}
```

That API is called via the following Javascript code

```
if ($("#myDetailsDataTable").length) {
    var myDataTable = $("#myDetailsDataTable").DataTable({
        "order": [[ 0, 'asc' ]],
        "stateSave": true,
        "stateDuration": -1,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "ajax": {
            url: "/ajax/my-ajax-api",
            type: "POST",
            dataSrc: "myResponseItem",
            data: function ( d ) {
                d.myId = $('#myId').val();
                console.log(d.myId)
                d.myOtherParameter = $('#myOtherParameter').val();
                console.log(d.myOtherParameter)
            }
        },
        "columns": [
        //Do a bunch of stuff with the column data here
        ]
    });

    setInterval( function () {
        myDataTable.ajax.reload(null, false);
    }, 3000 );

    myDataTable.on( 'xhr', function () {
        let ajaxResponseJson = myDataTable.ajax.json();
        //Do a bunch of stuff with the JSON
    });
}
```

The problem is that the `myId` and `myOtherParameter` parameters are not being assigned/populated by that `"ajax"` command, for some reason I cannot determine. The `console.log` statements have proved that they're definitely being populated in the Javascript when the call is made, so I don't know why they're being excluded from the API call.

This is the error response:

```
error: "Required request parameter 'myId' for method parameter type Long is not present"
path: ""
status: 400
```

This code works fine for other users. I have tried clearing my browser cache and making the call. I have also tried using another browser. But the same 400 error happens every time. I can only guess that it's something to do with my particular environment configuration. But I don't know what it could be. I am using Java 17, IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.1 and the latest Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works, even if I was unable to determine the root of the problem.

The issue is the Ajax POST request. It seems that on some machines the request parameters will be submitted as part of the request body instead, which was causing the Rest endpoint to respond with a Bad Request error.

The solution was to change the command to a GET request and change the endpoint to `GetMapping`.

```
"ajax": {
            url: "/ajax/my-ajax-api",
            type: "GET",
            dataSrc: "myResponseItem",
            data: function ( d ) {
                d.myId = $('#myId').val();
                d.myOtherParameter = $('#myOtherParameter').val();
            }
        }
```

```
@GetMapping(value = "/ajax/my-ajax-api")
public MyResponseDto runThisMethod(@RequestParam Long myId, @RequestParam Integer myOtherParameter) {
///
}
```